# jury nullification

Tags: jury, jury-nullification

I've heard about jury nullification, and I find it very interesting, but I don't know how it works exactly, and what is the legality of it. 
I've never dabbled in the "laws", so I'm not exactly knowledgeable about a lot of stuff... 
How legal is jury nullification actually ? 
Can they charge a non guilty person guilty whenever they want regardless of others opinions ? 
Can they let go of a guilty person despite perfect arguments if they so choose to ?

Comment: Do you have any question that is not already answered in [existing Q&A on the subject](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jury-nullification)?

Comment: I guess not....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jury ultimately decides if a person is guilty or not. Jury nullification is when the person is clearly guilty or innocent, but for some odd reason the jury (who knows the person is guilty/innocent) gives the "wrong verdict"

An example of this in the UK was when a guy was being charged with a spy crime years after his crime happened (I cant remember the case), the jury essentially thought that so much time has passed that it was silly to convict him, so gave a non guilty verdict.

There are cases for and against jury nullification.

In my personal belief I think in certain cases, such as if edward snowden would be charged, I would find him non guilty as a matter of what is right to ky conscience, regardless of the fact that he clearly did something illegal